# How should I create my events for the EventAggregator from P&P so subscribers on the UI thread can listen to them?

Tags: c#, eventaggregator

I am trying to update a progress bar in my main form while a background task is running.

I am using the EventAggregator from the latest Patterns & Practices release route my application wide events.

I am firing an event from a class listens to BackgroundWorker events and than fires an event as such:

1. Process on bw fires the BW method
   to report progress.
2. BW fires it's
   reporting events.
3. They get picked
   up by the SomeCommand class methods
   were set on the BW before it was
   launched.
4. I publish Events from
   the EventAggregator

public void ProgressChanged (object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs ea)
    {
        KnownProgressStatusChangedEvent evt = KernelKeeper.Kernel.Get().GetEvent();
        evt.Publish(ea);
    }

My MainPresenter has subscribed to those events as such:

```
    KnownProgressStatusChangedEvent progressChanged = EventAggregator.GetEvent<KnownProgressStatusChangedEvent>();
    progressChanged.Subscribe(KnownProgressChanged,ThreadOption.UIThread);
```

If I don't set the ThreadOption.UIThread I get TargetInvokationException in the Program.cs with no stack trace.
This way I get no exception and I can step in the EventAggregator.

When it is about to call the KnownProgressChanged method it tries to invoke it and checks for `Application.Current != null`. It is null and nothing is fired.

What am I doing wrong ? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TargetInvocationException was a red herring, which I caused by throwing a not implemented exception elsewhere in my code.

I am using WinForms and used the Subscribe with the ThreadOption.PublisherThread option and that works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify ThreadOption.UIThread because you are dealing with a progress bar, the handler must be called from the ui thread to be able to draw the new progress state.

Howerver if you are working with WPF you have to handle it without ThreadOption.UIThread and [dispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx#S3) the call yourself, you may take a look at the CompositeWpfEvent.

See [Event Aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707867.aspx) - Subscribing on the User Interface Thread

> Frequently, subscribers will need to
>   update user interface elements in
>   response to events. In Windows
>   Presentation Foundation (WPF), only a
>   UI thread can update user interface
>   elements. By default, the subscriber
>   receives the event on the publisher's
>   thread so if the publisher sends the
>   event from the UI thread, the
>   subscriber will be able to update the
>   user interface.
>
> However, if the publisher's thread is
>   a background thread, the subscriber
>   may be unable to directly update user
>   interface elements. Instead, it would
>   need to schedule the updates on the UI
>   thread using the Windows Presentation
>   Foundation's Dispatcher class. The
>   CompositeWpfEvent provided with the
>   Composite Application Library can
>   assist by allowing the subscriber to
>   automatically receive the event on the
>   UI thread. The subscriber must
>   indicate this during subscription, as
>   shown in the following code.
>
> ...

Comment: That is indeed what I have done. In bullet 5) I have listed the code.
Do I have to set it somewhere else ?